# Reshape Matrix and perform Zonal Statistics in Matlab

Tags: statistics, matlab, zonal-statistics

I have 2 grids: 1) **n** by **m** - at 100m 2) **n*10** by **m *10** - at 10m. These grids cover the same area.

I have to perform zonal statistics at scale of grid no.2. Cell value of grid no.1 is cumulative for the area, so before I'll do my zonal statistics, I need to reshape grid no. 1 in a way that all resulting cells of raster no. 1 would have fractional value (as per above example, say: 1 cell of value 100 would result in 100 cells of value 1).

After resizing my raster with proper values I need to perform zonal statistics on those 2 grids. In GIS enviroment it would not be a problem for me, but I have written in Matlab maybe 10 lines of code, so it may take some time till I get there. So I thought I'd ask if anyone had any experience in such calculation in Matlab.

Comment: Since the values in the first grid represent sums (are "cumulative") and because it sounds like you wish to apportion them by relative area, it suffices to divide the values in the first grid by 10*10 = 100 and assign them to all corresponding positions in the second grid. Then you're good to go. The Matlab-specific part of this question is more likely to get an answer on SO.